# Specifying location of agents that are generated within an agent that is placed on GIS map

Tags: anylogic

So in this model I have several hospital-agents that are placed randomly in an area. These hospitals contains a process flow and at some point in this process flow a new agent 'Bones' is generated, using a split block. The location of these Bones-agents is correctly specified by setting it equal to the (x,y) coordinates of the hospital.

Now I want to make the model more realistic by placing the hospitals in actual location in a GIS map. I did this with success. However, now I need to re-specify the location of the Bones-agents. At the moment of generating the first Bones-agent, I get the follow error:

```
root.Hospital1.splitblock: 
Error when trying to initialize new agent 
Caused by: root.Hospital2: 
This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Continuous, based on 
GIS map' and can't have behaviour for space 'Continuous'This agent is already 
defined as agent living in space 'Continuous, based on GIS map' and can't 
have behaviour for space 'Continuous'
```

What do I need to do to make this work? I have tried setting the location of the Bones-agent equal to the longitude and latitude of the hospital agent with a function:

```
double longitude = getLongitude();
return longitude;
```

I did the same for het latitude. I then inputted these functions in the 'latitude' fields of the split block.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop a model, you have to choose what kind of space you will use. Remember that all the canvas in which you put agents, and the map and stuff is based on a scale, so you can't mix a map with elements that are created with the space markup (with space markup i mean nodes, paths, rectangular nodes etc).

So the bones agents should also be placed in the map... It seems that you are not doing that, and you are probably placing the bones agent using the space markup.

But it's possible to do this of course, but you have to do it in another agent. Create a new agent called continuousSpace for instance, and place your bones agents there.

After that you will have to create a navigation button using viewAreas (from the presentation palette) to move from one agent to the other (meaning from the gis space to the markup space).

Otherwise, you can also place the bonesagents in the gis space (in the map) and it will also work.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, Felipe. You are correct: the agent in which Bones are generated is using space markup. The Bones need to able to move to other Hospital agents, so I guess I need to place the Bones in the GIS space. How would I implement place the bones in GIS space once they are generated at the split block? To be more clear: Hospitals live in GIS space, Bones are generated inside hospitals where space markup is used.

Comment: if they are generated with the split, there is an option in there "location of copy" that you can use...

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. Location of copy = (latitude, longitude). Then using the function in the OP to grab the lat and lon of the hospital agent. Unfortunately that yields that error

Comment: and what agent is creating these bones (what is the agent that exists before the split?)

Comment: Patients and hospitals both live in main (GIS map). Patients enter hospital and the process flow. The split block splits the patient agents in patients and in bones agents.

Comment: does it work if you choose the location as gis node and the node as new GISPoint(map,false,latitude,longitude)?

Comment: No it results in the same error. I've edited the OP to include the full error message, which may be of use.

Comment: I would have to see the model.. I don't know exactly what's going on